# How do I create A JavaScript Random Number Generator That Uses HTML Input, and Button Elements?

Tags: javascript, function, dom, random, getelementsbyclassname

My goal is to create a random number generator that accepts user input via HTML, and allows the user to click "submit" in order to return a random number between the 2 values.

I AM STUCK... Where do I go from here?

HTML: -------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
<html>

<input type="text" class="min"><br>
<input type="text" class="max"><br>
<button class="button">Submit</button>

</html>
```

Javascript:---------------------------------------------------------------------

```
function myRand(min, max) {

var min = document.getElementByClassName(min).value;

var max = document.getElementByClassName(max).value;

var button = document.getElementByClassName(button);

var result = Math.floor(Math.random()) * (max - min) + min;

return result;
}
```

Comment: You've got a fair number of errors in your code.

Comment: Could you point me in the right direction? I was able to get the random number function to work (before i declared the min, max, and button variables inside the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things that aren't quite right:

1. `getElementByClassName` is not a function - it should be `getElementsByClassName` (notice that `Elements` is plural). This indicates that an array of elements are returned, rather than just one element. Therefore, you'll need to do something like `getElementsByClassName(...)[0].value`. Alternatively, you can use ids + `getElementById`.
2. You're passing in the arguments `min` and `max` to `getElementByClassName`. I would think you mean to pass a string to this function, e.g. `getElementsByClassName("min")`. This way, you won't need arguments to the `myRand` function
3. The value of the input fields is going to be a string, not a number. You'll need to convert it to a number using something like `parseInt`
4. You're never actually calling `myRand`. If you wanted to call it after pressing the button, you could add an `onclick` listener to the button.
5. The random number generation itself isn't correct. You're first calling `Math.floor` on `Math.random()`, but since `Math.random()` returns a number between 0 and 1 (not including 1), the result will always be 0 (and so, the variable `result` will always be set to `min`). Instead, it should look like: `Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min`

Below is a fiddle which takes these changes into account, and illustrates how to use `getElementById` to render the result to the screen:

https://jsfiddle.net/xv2ne0b9/13/

Comment: Worked Like a charm! Thank you. I was able to duplicate your outcome using getElementById.

Answer (score -2):

var min = document.getElementByClassName(min)[0].value;
var max = document.getElementByClassName(max)[0].value;

Comment: 1. Please format your code. 2. There are syntax errors in your code. 3. This _still_ won't work, as there are more errors in the original post.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I'm a newbie and don't know how to format the code.